# Create list of all days per month and split value equally to each day

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=29e567df8cd8e7c40bf9637cfa1f714c)**

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    entry_date DATE,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(entry_date, costs)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01', '500'),
('2020-02-01', '325'),
('2020-03-01', '200'),
('2020-04-01', '400'),
('2020-05-01', '900'),
('2020-06-01', '700'),
('2020-07-01', '900'),
('2020-08-01', '100'),
('2020-09-01', '300'),
('2020-10-01', '850'),
('2020-11-01', '470'),
('2020-12-01', '800');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
date_list     |          costs
--------------|----------------------------
2020-01-01    |      16.12  (=500/31)
2020-01-02    |      16.12  (=500/31)
2020-01-03    |      16.12  (=500/31)
2020-01-04    |      16.12  (=500/31)
:             |      :
:             |      :
2020-12-29    |      25.81  (=800/31)
2020-12-30    |      25.81  (=800/31)
2020-12-31    |      25.81  (=800/31)
```

---

In the table I have costs per month assigned to one day per month. 
Now, I want to create a list of all days per month and split the costs of each month equally to each of those days.

```
SELECT
entry_date, 
SUM(costs) AS costs
FROM costs
GROUP BY 1;
```

Do you have any idea how do I have to modify the query to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb49f98c94e78ee5e10ab56775dd331c)

```
SELECT
    gs::date,
    costs /  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY entry_date)    -- 3
FROM costs,
    generate_series(                                    -- 2
        entry_date,
        entry_date + interval '1 month - 1 day',        -- 1
        interval '1 day'
    ) gs
```

1. Calculation of the last day of month (add a month to the first of the month to get the first day of the next month, subtract one day from it)
2. Generate a date series from start to end of a month
3. The join of your data with the generated series already duplicated the costs values, which only need to be divided by the day count of each month, which is what the `COUNT()` window function does here

Comment: *"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BY"
LINE 3:     costs / COUNT(PARTITION BY entry_date)"* using this query in the fiddle.

Comment: @S-Man . . . I'm not the only one who gets downvotes on accepted answers.  ;)