# Assign value to day per month and only display selected days in query result

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

[**DB-Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72e4e8375a23c49b99ba3a60e17cf347)

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    entry_date DATE,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(entry_date, costs)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01', '500'),
('2020-02-01', '325'),
('2020-03-01', '200'),
('2020-04-01', '400'),
('2020-05-01', '900'),
('2020-06-01', '700'),
('2020-07-01', '900'),
('2020-08-01', '100'),
('2020-09-01', '300'),
('2020-10-01', '850'),
('2020-11-01', '470'),
('2020-12-01', '800');
```

**Exptected Result:**

```
date_list     |          costs
--------------|----------------------------
2020-05-01    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-02    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-03    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-04    |      29.03  (=900/31)
```

---

In the table I have costs per month assigned to one day per month. 
Now I want to do the following:

1. Divide the costs through the days of the months to get the costs per day.
2. Only display the dates that are selected in the WHERE-Clause of the query.

---

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598075/create-list-of-all-days-per-month-and-split-value-equally-to-each-day) I tried this query:

```
SELECT
    gs::date AS entry_date,
    costs / date_part('day', entry_date + interval '1 month - 1 day') AS costs
FROM costs,

    generate_series(
        entry_date,
        entry_date + interval '1 month - 1 day',
        interval '1 day'
    ) gs
    
WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-04'
```

The query does the first step of the expected result. 
However, as you can see in the [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72e4e8375a23c49b99ba3a60e17cf347) it does show all days of the month and is not limitied to the `2020-05-04`.

How do I need to change the query to also make the WHERE-condition work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach is a little inverted.  You want one row per date, so use `generate_series()` to generate those days.  And you can do so explicitly.

Then just do the arithmetic to get what you want:

```
SELECT gs.entry_date,
       c.costs / date_part('day', date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) + interval '1 month - 1 day') AS costs
FROM costs c join lateral
     generate_series('2020-05-01'::date, '2020-05-04'::date, interval '1 day') as gs(entry_date)
     on date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) = c.entry_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d10d9abd062325a0b91658487b937313) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I run it in the DB-Fiddle it work. In Redshift I get ERROR: syntax error at or near "'2020-05-01'" Position: 219. How do I have to modify the query to also make it work in redshift?

Answer (score 1):

If you put the `WHERE` clause into the same query, it just filters your original table, which results in the May record. This will be used to do all the magic and will be expanded. That's why you get all May days.

You have to put the `WHERE` into a subquery because first you need to do the calculation and then you can filter it:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1a29024cb5f3d4ddf2160fe7544cb6dd)

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (

    SELECT
        gs::date AS entry_date,
        costs / date_part('day', entry_date + interval '1 month - 1 day') AS costs
    FROM costs,

        generate_series(
            entry_date,
            entry_date + interval '1 month - 1 day',
           interval '1 day'
        ) gs
    
) s   
WHERE entry_date BETWEEN '2020-05-01' AND '2020-05-04'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Before I open a new question maybe we can solve it here already. Since my original database is mucht bigger than the example it would be great if the query could already limit the generate_series to the days I need in the end. Is this modifcation easy to make in your query?

Comment: @Michi In that case I'd go with Gordon's solution.

Comment: Thanks. Upvote for your answer and additional support.