# Assign monthly value to each day of the month in redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d8832f5c45f8879892fe0780253245c9)**

```
CREATE TABLE costs (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    entry_date DATE,
    costs DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO costs
(entry_date, costs)
VALUES 

('2020-01-01', '500'),
('2020-02-01', '325'),
('2020-03-01', '200'),
('2020-04-01', '400'),
('2020-05-01', '900'),
('2020-06-01', '700'),
('2020-07-01', '900'),
('2020-08-01', '100'),
('2020-09-01', '300'),
('2020-10-01', '850'),
('2020-11-01', '470'),
('2020-12-01', '800');
```

**Exptected Result:**

```
date_list     |          costs
--------------|----------------------------
2020-05-01    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-02    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-03    |      29.03  (=900/31)
2020-05-04    |      29.03  (=900/31)
```

---

In the table I have costs per month assigned to one day per month.
Now I want to do the following:

1. Divide the costs through the days of the months to get the costs per day.
2. Only display the dates that are selected in the WHERE-Clause of the query.

---

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66598891/assign-value-to-day-per-month-and-only-display-selected-days-in-query-result) I tried this query:

```
SELECT 
gs.entry_date,
c.costs / date_part('day', date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) + interval '1 month - 1 day') AS costs
FROM costs c
JOIN
generate_series('2020-05-01'::date, '2020-05-04'::date, interval '1 day') AS gs(entry_date)
ON date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) = c.entry_date
```

The query works in `Postgres` but in `Redshift` I get this error:

```
ERROR: function generate_series(date, date, interval) does not exist Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

What function do I need to replace the `generate_series` part to get the same results in `redshift`?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift simply doesn't have a convenient date generation function. If your table is big enough (and it should be in Redshift), you can generate one in the query:

```
WITH gs as (
      SELECT '2020-05-01'::date + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER () - 1) * INTERVAL '1 DAY' as entry_date
      FROM costs
      LIMIT 4
     )
SELECT gs.entry_date,
       c.costs / date_part('day', date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) + interval '1 month' - interval '1 day') AS costs
FROM costs c JOIN
      gs
      ON date_trunc('month', gs.entry_date) = c.entry_date;
```

If you have a calendar table or a numbers table, you can use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have a calender table in my database so I used this table but I get an error on the interval part: ERROR: Interval values with month or year parts are not supported

Comment: @Michi . . . I *think* you can break it into two intervals.  Or you might have to use `add_months()`.